# Get value from associative array when all array value matched

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check if values are the same in an associative array and return that value not true in javascript.
Something with find or filter method.
Able to check every element but couldn't return the specific value in the result.

Example :
[image]

If all values of array.id is same return id

```
OUTPUT = 1
```

Comment: I have edited it. Please check. Thank You

Comment: Please write it with valid JS syntax, probably `const workloads = [{id: 1}, ...];`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: I don't want true and false I want to return the value. Every method returns boolean value only.

Comment: And what should be the return if not all ids the same? Perhaps false, null, undefined, ...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, it makes it hard to make a distinction between successfull and failed check. As Sascha asked, what to return when the ids don't match? Use `every`, and if it returns `true`, just read the first value ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the id from the first object and go with [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) over it. If this is for all true  than return the ID otherwise false.

**Note:** You didn't told us what to return if not all have the same id, so I take `false` but you can take a value of your own choice.

```js
function checkAllSame (workloads) {
    const ID = workloads[0].id; 
    return (workloads.every(({id}) => id===ID)) ? ID : false;
}

console.log(checkAllSame([{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id:1}]));
console.log(checkAllSame([{id: 2}, {id: 1}, {id:1}]));
console.log(checkAllSame([{id: 7, color: 'green'}, {id: 7, type: 'car'}, {id:7}, {id:7}]));
```

Comment: Sascha and Teemu you both are right. Thanks for your effort. After a good sleep, I thought the same.